# Executable Jar file not working another machine

Tags: java

I have created an executable jar file to my java programm using Eclipse(File->Export).

When i double click the jar it works fine.After i copy the jar file to another machine(windows) i got an error "Invalid or corrupt jarfile".I have installed JRE and JVM.

Anybody know what is the issue.
Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
vks

Comment: The crystal ball is hazy today. How did you do the file transfer?

Comment: Have you tired `jar tvf your-jafile.jar`? This is going to list the contents of your jar file: if it doesn't succeed then the jar file is likely to be corrupted (maybe something happened when you copied it from one machine to another)

Comment: @larsmans  i just attach the jar to email and send, download it to the othermachine

Comment: @MarcoS got the error 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @vks: if you're sure that Java is installed in the Windows machine, then you have a problem with your PATH variable. I'm not very familiar with windows, but do something like `echo %PATH` from the command prompt, and see that your PATH includes the `bin` directory of your Java installation. Have a look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/397389/java/java/jar-not-recognized-as-internal)

Comment: @MarcoS but java command is working .

Comment: @vks: it depends how java has been installed (on Windows I'm not sure). Have you checked the PATH environment variable?

Comment: @MarcoS I only installed JRE in my machine not Jdk or JSDK, i think an execuitable jar oly need JVM

Comment: Your error message tells us nothing. Do you have a detailed log --perhaps you can run it from the command line (as Ravi replied below) and paste the error messages?

Comment: @marcoS as @vks said Os is windows. so `jar tvf` is not for windows

Comment: @vks be specific for your problem and give all details needed to help you as we are not debating here.

Comment: @vks: OK, if `jar tvf` is not for Windows (as _Ravi Parekh_ writes), then simply rename your jarfile as `whatever.zip` and try to open it as zip file: see if you can open it.

Answer (score 1):

as you said you have `double click`
try  command line as another machine(windows) might not be assign `jar` extension to execute.
to run jar manually do.

`java -jar example.jar`

Comment: Please don't abbreviate the word "you".